# Error:Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am using the thymeleaf and spring. i want to implement the post request.

my controller class is

```
public class URLController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "index")
    public String index1(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());

        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/result")
    public String result(@ModelAttribute Employee employee){
        System.out.print(employee.getName());
        return "result";
    }
}
```

and the html page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/result}" modelAttribute="employee" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
    <p>phone: <input type="text" th:field="*{phone}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

there is no binding with the id field.

Comment: Well, do you have the "id" field in `Employee` class?

Comment: Yes i have the id in the entity

Comment: And getter for the id field?

Comment: yes i do have the getters and setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, you need to use the proper syntax for your model attribute.  Spring is complaining that it can't find the property `id` because you are providing the string `employee`, not the object.

`modelAttribute="employee" --> th:object="${employee}"`

Additionally, you can consolidate to:

```
@Controller //please add this
public class URLController {

    @GetMapping({"/", "/index"})
    public String index1(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/result")
    public String result(@ModelAttribute Employee employee){
        System.out.print(employee.getName()); //use a logger instead
        return "result"; //may want to return a different page name for clarity
    }
}
```

Your IDE will not complain if you change your HTML tag to:

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`

Lastly, you may want to use the `tel` input type for the phone field.  Doing so will allow for a custom keyboard to show for mobile users.

Comment: after adding that i am getting the error  Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'employee' available as request attribute

Comment: the github link for the project is     https://github.com/dishankgoyal/springsBoot/tree/master/springs

Comment: See my PR on github